# containsObject in ios always returns no

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

my `favouriteMark` array has following objects `((no),(no),(no))` but when i tried to `containsObject` it always returns NO.

```
if([favouriteMark containsObject:@"no"] == YES)
{
NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Its not getting into if condition.

Comment: What are this objects in the array? What type is `(no)`? How are you creating the array?

Comment: Actually its has objects from database. In log it showed like that only ((no), (no))

Comment: Yes, but it will still have a type. Is it a bool? string? something else?

Comment: in database its varchar

Comment: If the above `((no),(no),(no))` is what you actually see when you NSLog that array then it contains objects with are logging as `(no)`.  One possibility is that these are NSArrays containing a single string with a value of `@"no"`, but there are other possibilities.  None of the possibilities will compare equal to `@"no"`.

Comment: @Balaji OK try this... `NSLog(@"%@", [favouriteMark[0] class]);` and see what it says.

Comment: @Fogmeister - `[favouriteMark = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.databaseCall loadFromDB:query]];`

Comment: @Balaji ok cool, let me know what the NSLog in my last question shows.

Comment: @Fogmeister - NSLog shows `((no), (no), (no), (no), (no), (no))`

Comment: @Balaji What you have done there is `NSLog("%@", favouriteMark);` that is not what I put in my comment. Look at my comment (6th comment on the question). Tell me the result of that NSLog statement.

Comment: @Balaji have you put the NSLog statement in that I suggested? If you let us have a look at that it will tell us how we can help :)

Comment: @Fogmeister - It Shows _NSArrayM

Comment: @Balaji ok, cool. So your array is actually an array of arrays. Now you need to do this... `NSLog(@"%@", [favouriteMark[0][0] class]);` **notice the double [0][0]** this will tell you what the class of the objects inside the arrays is :)

Comment: @Fogmeister - It shows _NSCFString

Comment: @Balaji ok, added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your array is an array of arrays and each array contains a string (very random).

Anyway, you can change your code like this...

```
if([favouriteMark containsObject:@[@"no"]]) // don't need to have == YES
{
    // it contains @[@"no"]
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. Its working like a charm.. May i have ur mail id, facebook id, twitter. whatsapp

Comment: @Balaji Glad it's working. You can find my details in my profile page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653106/frame-is-not-changing-in-cellforrowatindexpath, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636660/frame-of-view-inside-the-cell-not-changing-in-cellforrowatindexpath, Can u please answer the above questions? Because u have helped me in this app before.

Answer (score 1):

This works propertly:

```
 NSArray *noArray = @[@"no",@"no",@"no"];
 if ([noArray containsObject:@"no"])
 {
    NSLog(@"No array contains no");
 }
```

And this also work:

```
     NSArray *noArray = @[@NO,@NO,@NO];
if ([noArray containsObject:@NO])
{
    NSLog(@"No array contains no");
}
```

You must compare the same object kind.

Last option:

```
NSArray *noArray = @[@[@"no"],@[@"no"],@[@"no"]];
NSLog(@"This array look like your array : %@",[noArray description]);

if ([noArray containsObject:@[@"no"]])
{
    NSLog(@"No array contains no");
}
```

Comment: It may do. But that `noArray` is not the same as the `favouriteMark` array that the OP has.

Comment: Actually i am getting arrayList from database. `[favouriteMark = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.databaseCall loadFromDB:query]];`

Comment: @Fogmeister what's kind of object has your favouriteMark array ?

Comment: @Balaji that fact is actually completely irrelevant. Whether it is coming from a DB or JSON or code you have an array. The answer here is trying to show a couple of different examples. We still don't know WHAT is in the array though.

Comment: @OnikIV no idea, that's what I'm trying to find out from Balaji.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have and array that has the same NSLog, but It might work or not.

Comment: @OnikIV: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653106/frame-is-not-changing-in-cellforrowatindexpath, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636660/frame-of-view-inside-the-cell-not-changing-in-cellforrowatindexpath, Can u please answer the above questions?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, replace `containsObject:` with a brute-force search and set breakpoints to see what's going on:

```
for(NSObject *element in favouriteMark) {
    if([element compare:@"no"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"Element %@ matches.", element);
        break;
    } else {
         // set breakpoint and inspect element if desired
        NSLog(@"Element %@ of class %@ does not match.", element, [element class]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: We still don't know what type of object is actually in the array though. You are assuming here that the objects in the array are instances of NSString. From the log in the first line I very much doubt that is the case.

Comment: I am not assuming they are strings at all. They will never compare if not NSStrings of course, but you can set a breakpoint on the second NSLog and inspect element. I'll edit to add another useful piece of info.