# Frame of View inside the cell not changing in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a View inside the tableViewCell. In certain conditions I want to move the view to some origin `x` but the following code not working in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If i use the code after the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets completed, its working fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GoalDetailsCustomCardCell" bundle:nil];

[goalDetailsTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [goalDetailsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [goalDetailsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
}
if([self.swipedRowArray containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
                cell.cardDetails.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.cardDetails.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
                //        CGRectOffset(cell.cardView.frame, -320.0, 0.0);
                cell.actionCardReminder.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.actionCardReminder.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
            }];
}
}
```

Can anyone Help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with follwoing way.
GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [goalDetailsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCel%d",indexPath.row];

Comment: That too not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this animation block in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(GoalDetailsTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([self.swipedRowArray containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
                cell.cardDetails.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.cardDetails.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
                //        CGRectOffset(cell.cardView.frame, -320.0, 0.0);
                cell.actionCardReminder.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.actionCardReminder.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
            }];
  }
}
```

I am not sure whether it will work for you or not, but I have added cell animations in this method only.

Hope this helps to you as well.

Comment: Its showing Property `cardDetails` not found on object of Type `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: It requires type conversion before using it, as you're using custom cell. Updated my answer.

Comment: It would be better, if you mention the error details, while you add comment.

Comment: It shows the error Property `cardDetails not found on object of Type UITableViewCell`

Comment: Sorry. Now the error has gone but the view is not moved.

Comment: But its not moving to negative `x` origin