# Frame is not changing in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the x position frame of `view` inside the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for certain conditions. I have used the following code. But it does not change the view's `x position` frame.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GoalDetailsCustomCardCell" bundle:nil];

        [goalDetailsTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [goalDetailsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCell"];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [goalDetailsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardCell"];
        }

    NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.origin.x);
                [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
                    cell.cardDetails.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.cardDetails.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
                    //        CGRectOffset(cell.cardView.frame, -320.0, 0.0);
                    cell.actionCardReminder.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.actionCardReminder.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
                }];
                NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.origin.x);

    return cell;
    }
```

The view in cell moving as expected but not to the negative side. Its still showing the cardDetails view not the actionCardReminder view.

Note: The NSLog show the view frame as change x position but the view is not moving to -322.0 position.

Comment: you are using autolayout? and do not register nib on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. register it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Since the xposition is -322.0 for cardDetails view how did you determine that it's not working. is view's width greater than the screen?

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani: I have updated my question pls have a look. I think u have understood my question and going in right path.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the iOS layout render process, your custom UITableViewCell's layoutSubviews may called more than once. In your case you can change the items frames in the GoalDetailsTableViewCell class's layoutSubviews method.

```
@implementation GoalDetailsTableViewCell

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
                    cell.cardDetails.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.cardDetails.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
                    //        CGRectOffset(cell.cardView.frame, -320.0, 0.0);
                    cell.actionCardReminder.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.actionCardReminder.frame, -322.0, 0.0);
                }];
     NSLog(@"%f", cell.cardDetails.frame.origin.x);
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not change the Frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` try Changing it in `willDisplayingCell` Method

Comment: I see that You are using A Custom NIb y dont you adjust the coordinate in the Nib file itself

Comment: Actually I want to change the frame only certain conditions.

Comment: try in willDisplayingCell method then